# How to get all arguments of a callback function

Tags: javascript, callback, arguments

Very often, I find myself using a callback function and I don't have its documentation handy, and it would be nice to see all of the arguments that are meant to be passed to that callback function.

```
// callback is a function that I don't know the args for...
// and lets say it was defined to be used like: callback(name, number, value)
something.doSomething( callback );
```

How can I determine what args its passing into that?

Note: looking at the source code can be unhelpful when the code itself is obfuscated and minified (as many js frameworks are)

Comment: `arguments` http://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2011/01/18/javascripts-arguments-object-and-beyond/

Comment: parameters should be defined by the callee, not the caller?

Comment: You can often look at the source code for the calling function even if you don't have the documentation handy.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

To get the list of arguments without breaking functionality, overwrite the callback function in this way:

```
var original = callback;
callback = function() {
    // Do something with arguments:
    console.log(arguments);
    return original.apply(this, arguments);
};
```

1. The context, [`this`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) is preserved.
2. All arguments are correctly passed.
3. The return value is correctly passed.

NOTE: This method works in most cases. Though there are edge cases where this method will fail, including:

- Read-only properties (e.g. defined using `Object.defineProperty` with `writable:false`)
- Properties that are defined using getters/setters, when the getter/setter is not symmetric.
- Host objects and plugin APIs: E.g. Flash and ActiveX.

Comment: PS. For even more details, add [`console.trace();`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/console.trace) to the replaced callback function.

Comment: Why `return original.apply(this, arguments);` isn't enough?

Comment: @gdoron Some browsers throw an error when  `.apply(<anything>, <NOT A TRUE ARRAY>)` is used. See also: [MDN: `Function.apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply#Parameters). The [`arguments`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/arguments) object is not a true array.

Comment: @RobW: If you're talking about the note that starts `Note: Most browsers, including Chrome 14 and Internet Explorer 9...`, it doesn't apply to the Arguments object. I don't know of any browser that won't accept an Arguments object as the second argument to `.apply()`. *Side note, this was recently fixed in Chrome so any Array-like object will work.*

Comment: @amnotiam. "The note on _apply_ doesn't _apply_..." The human language  at it best. **:-)**

Comment: @gdoron: Indeed. :) FYI, I just verified this in IE6. The Arguments object is accepted by `.apply()` with no problems.

Comment: @amnotiam Ok, thanks for verifying. I remembered an issue with array-likes and `.apply()`, supposedly not on `arguments` :o

Comment: I'm working on a snippet using Harmony Proxies to dynamically "objectize" the DOM and your code just solved my problem accessing the functions through a Proxy. You saved me a lot of trouble. Thanks

Comment: This is essentially AOP: Aspect Oriented Programming.  I've blogged about it including this answer here: https://dev.to/dexygen/quick-and-dirty-aspect-oriented-aop-javascript-with-a-couple-dozen-lines-of-code-484b

Comment: Worse to mention that this doesn't work in arrrow functions.

Answer (score 8):

Could it be as easy as

```
function callback() {
    console.log(arguments);
}
```

?

Every function provides the arguments it has been called with in the automagic `arguments` collection.

Comment: He can't change the callback code. If he could, he wouldn't need to use the arguments to know what it's arguments...

Comment: Where did he say that? Since when can't you change JS code? Apart from that, a JS debugger and a breakpoint are just a few clicks away.

Comment: He wrote he doesn't want to look at the documentions of the func, so for sure he doesn't have that function code handly...

Comment: add in `console.log(this)` and you have a complete view of the local(est) scope.

Comment: this is a frequent sort of problem when you're dealing with minified / obfuscated code... like anything jquery/mootools/etc

Comment: @gdoron I don't know about you, but I usually have all the JS code handy that I'm working with. ;) Also, callback functions are the ones that *I* write. Why would I care about the arguments if I'm not currently writing that function?

Answer (score 1):

Isn't this sort of the cart leading the horse?

*Your* function takes a callback. It's the method using *your* function that should be aware of what arguments the callback should accept.

Comment: that would be true if it were *my* function, but +1 for good use of italics. haha ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can even tell it which function's args to get using [functionName].arguments:

```
(function(arg1, arg2, agr3){
    console.log('args are:', arguments);
    return function fn(){
        function m(){
            console.log(
                'fn.arguments:', fn.arguments,
                'm.arguments:', m.arguments,
                'argumentsX:', arguments
            );
        };
        m('mArg1', 'mArg2', 'mArg3', 'mArg4');
    };
})
(1, 2, Math.PI)  // invoke closure
('fnArg1', 'fnArg2', 'fnArg3', 'fnArg4');  // invoke "fn"
```

Every function def rewrites the the arguments keyword to be of that scope btw (as seen with the "`argumentsX`" log).